# Data frames and vectors management

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have a data frame with one column of characters and the rest of the columns are consisted of integers. What i wanna do is check the values of a specific column (5) and if they are >1000, insert the value to a newly created vector. So far, Ive come up with this solution, but I come across an error in my if statement. Any help would be appreciated.

D is the dataframe

```
greaterthan1000 <- vector ('numeric',length = nrow(D))
for (i in 1:nrow(D)){
   if(D[[i]][[5]]>1000){
     greaterthan1000 <- c(D[[i]][[5]])
   }
}
```

Error:

> Error in if (D[[i]][[5]] > 1000) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed

In addition:

> Warning message: In Ops.factor(B[[i]][[5]], 1000) : ‘>’ not meaningful
>   for factors

Comment: `greaterthan1000 = D[[5]][D[[5]] > 1000]` will work, no for loop needed. In your code, replace `D[[i]][[5]]` with `D[[5]][i]`.

Comment: Though, given your warning, you might also want to check the class. If `class(D[[5]])` is a factor you probably want `D[[5]] = as.numeric(as.character(D[[5]]))` first.

Comment: ok, gimme a sec and ill check both. thanks in advance though

Comment: Ι decided to use a fully numeric data frame, cause im thinking my professor has messed up the exercise (found many errors after that). If it wasnt a fault I will put the question again. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```
greaterthan1000 <- D[D[, 5] > 1000, 5]
```